# Manually load ZF2 modules from a custom location

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-modules

I wonder if there is any way to load modules manually. It means, say I have a module named `Application` and another module named `Clients`. I do not want the `Clients` module goes into the `application.config.php` file and keep loading automatically regardless of application preference. I should manually load it from within my first module named `Application`. It can also be from any custom location other than 'module' directory.

Welcome any decent answers. Thank you geeks.

Comment: If you have a autoloader you can just use the use statement and call the class. Else just require once it in you vustom application class and then use it.

Comment: ok as per your comment,, do you mean should I autoload the module.php file? Module class has several things. Just loading the class might not help without executing the proper function on them.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: Probably an dependancy. But no dic

Comment: @TimFountain to create my own module handler. So I have the control of enabling/disabling of mudule within my application.

Answer (score 1):

No, Zend Framework 2 does not allow you to load modules from another module. This is specifically not provided to prevent unwanted side effects. There are two things you have to specify:

1. The module's loading path; where to look when you load a module
2. The modules you want to load; which modules you enlist are enabled

You cannot have a module which is not listed in the application config but loaded anyhow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any way I came up with a workaround. I will post it once done.

Comment: I posted the workaround below. if you can give me a quick review pelase.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround to achieve the desired requirements. I post it here so that any one find this question can get benefit out of it.

The concept is actually to pass the verified modules along with the main configuration processed by a custom class. So that it will be automatically loaded by the native module manager of zend.

1.First add the new path of modules to main configuration file.

`<?php
return array(
    // other options
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
            './my_module_path', // << HERE WE ADD THE DESIRED MODULE PATH
        ),
    // .......
);`

2.Create a class function in our main module to check which of the modules are enabled and get the list

`<?php
namespace Application;
class MyModuleManager
{
    public static function AddCustomModules(array $modules) {
        // find and create the available module array $custom_modules;
        return array_merge ($modules, $custom_modules);
    }
}`

3.Alter `index.php` file located at `public` directory to inject the modified configuration with the newly loaded module list.

```
//
// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(_my_get_configs(require 'config/application.config.php'))->run();

// Custom function to process custom modules
function _my_get_configs(array $config) {
    if (class_exists ('Application\MyModuleManager')) {
        $module_merged = \Application\MyModuleManager::AddCustomModules($confi['modules']);
        $config['modules'] = $module_merged;
    }
    return $config;
}
```

The above are just an abstraction of my concept which I implemented and working. I can not post the full code, so get only the concept from above. If any one can improve the above architecture, please suggest.

Comment: You can create a specific listener for the existing module manager. Listen for the `EVENT_LOAD_MODULE` event with a prio [between 9000 and 8000](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/DefaultListenerAggregate.php#L49-L53). This listener should have access to the instance of the ModuleManager itself. Then you check the dependencies of the module and call [`$moduleManager->loadModule($name)`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php#L131).

Comment: Note you have to check for circular dependencies and track the stack depth, otherwise you could get into an infinite loop. The only trick would be to attach a listener to the module manager's event manager. But it is much more clean as you now have to define all dependencies upfront while with the event system you could let modules load other modules.

Comment: let me go through it. More appreciated if you can give an example as an answer.